# pgloader - mysql to postgres DB migration with materialized views

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, view, pgloader

I am trying to migrate a database from mysql to postgresql using pgloader.. I am using materialized views. Although my case is pretty complicated, everything works perfectly for loading data, and handling keys and indexes. However, pgloader cannot be able to migrate views from the source (mssql) databases. I have visited [doc](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/2079646c81f565b5e9edba627d14cbf63af2dbdd/docs/ref/mysql.rst) to load file for migration.. But I want to run it as a command.

in mysql database it has 3 views (user_without_device, device_in_range, group_zero_access)

when I migrate using pgloader, all the tables are migrated from mysql.. But views are not migrated..

commands are,

```
pgloader mysql://root:password@localhost/currentdb postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/newdb
```